# transformPdfFields and field visibility

Tags: docusignapi

I've noticed that default transformPdfFields behavior (both API and site) omits tabs that have their form field common property set to "Visible but doesn't print" so they are not transformed and are not accessible. Is it possible to somehow change this behavior when making a request without actually changing the document field properties?

Comment: Not sure you mean by "the behavior omits tabs that are in visible but doesn't print".  Please elaborate on your question...

Comment: These tabs (signature tabs especially) do not get converted to DocuSign SecureFields.
'Visible but doesn't print' is one of visibility options for Adobe pdf fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I don't believe you can convert these fields through DocuSign settings.  You'll have to use a different form field property in your Adobe settings when saving the PDF if you want those Adobe form fields converted into DocuSign Stick-eTabs.  The api guide has more info on this.  Directly from the [DocuSign REST API guide](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm) it states:

```
Only the following FieldTypes and FieldProperties are extrapolated from the forms:
```

*FieldTypes* that are extrapolated:

- CheckBox
- DateTime
- ListBox
- Numeric
- Radio
- Text
- Signature
- Password

*FieldProperties* that are extrapolated:

- ReadOnly
- Required
- MaxLength
- Positions
- Initial Data

For more information please see this page from the API guide -
http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Document%20Parameters.htm

Comment: Well, actually those are 'Signature' fields. Fixing visibility property to 'Visible' seems to fix the issue so I'll have to iTextSharp all the way. But I still don't get how this property affects the behavior of DocuSign conversion if it should not be extrapolated as your guide states.